# Bash .hushlogin, keep last login time and host

Tags: bash, login, motd

At my company, when I log into some servers, my last login and a huge banner are displayed:

```
me@my-laptop$ ssh the-server
Last login: Mon Feb  8 18:54:36 2016 from my-laptop.company.com 
************************************************************************
*                                                                      *
*       C O M P A N Y    I N F O R M A T I O N   S Y S T E M S         *
*                                                                      *
* !WARNING!         Your connection has been logged          !WARNING! *
*                                                                      *
* This system is for the use of authorized personnel only.             *
* Individuals using this *computer system without authorization,       *
* or in excess of their authority as determined by the Company         *
* Code of Ethics and  Acceptable Use Policy, are subject to having all *
* of their activities on this system monitored, recorded and/or        *
* terminated by system personnel.                                      *
* If such monitoring reveals possible evidence of criminal  activity,  *
* Company may provide said evidence to law enforcement officials,      *
* in compliance with its confidentiality obligations and all           *
* applicable national laws/regulations with regards to data privacy.   *
*                                                                      *
*      This device is maintained by Company Department                 *
*                  admin@company.com                                   *
************************************************************************
me@the-server$
```

Of course, I don't want this huge banner displayed every time I login, but I would like to *keep the last login time and host displayed*.

If I use `touch ~/.hushlogin`, the banner is not displayed but I also loose the the
*last login information*. In fact, nothing at all is displayed:

```
ssh the-server
me@the-server$
```

How do I remove the banner but keep the last login time and host, like this:

```
 ssh the-server
 Last login: Mon Feb  8 18:54:36 2016 from my-laptop.company.com
 me@the-server$
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way would be to add the following to `~/.ssh/rc`, which contains commands to be run when you ssh into the machine:

```
lastlog -u $USER | perl -lane 'END{print "Last login: @F[3..6] $F[8] from $F[2]"}'
```

The command will get the time of your last login from `lastlogin` and then format it so that it looks like the original version. You can now `touch ~/.hushlogin` and you will still see that message.

Comment: Nice one. I finally went for `last -w | grep "$USER" | head -n1 | perl -lane 'END{print "Last login: @F[3..6] $F[8] from $F[2]"}'` because `lastlog` was truncating my hostname.

Comment: @Xion345  Rather than grepping for your username (which might get you someone else with a longer username that contains yours), you can use `last -w "$USER" | ...` there

Comment: You also might want to know if the /etc/motd changes, so could also add: cmp /etc/motd ~/.hushlogin.motd || cat /etc/motd && cp /etc/motd ~/.hushlogin.motd

Comment: But if I want the untruncated long hostname, `-a` should be added, then the format gets some shift:

`last -a $USER | perl -lane '!/still logged in/ && print "Last login: @F[2..5] from $F[$#F]" and last'`

Comment: @saulius2 that sounds like it would be worth posting as a separate answer, explaining why the tweaks were needed for that OS. It will be lost in the comments.

Comment: @terdon, thanks for the encouragement.

Answer (score 15):

Having your `.bash_profile` call `lastlog -u "$USER"` gets you something pretty close. Output looks like:

```
Username         Port     From             Latest
anthony          pts/7    192.168.XX.YY    Sun Feb  7 16:00:40 -0500 2016
```

where of course I redacted the IP address.

`last -w -n 1` gets a similar record, but from a different database.

Answer (score 7):

The **right way** to do it is this one:

edit the files: **/etc/pam.d/login**  and **/etc/pam.d/sshd**
and comment these lines:

```
# Prints the message of the day upon successful login.
# (Replaces the `MOTD_FILE' option in login.defs)
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
#session    optional   pam_motd.so motd=/run/motd.dynamic
#session    optional   pam_motd.so noupdate
```

and remove **.hushlogin** or **/etc/huslogin** if you "touched" it.

That's all.

Result:

```
zibris login: zibri
Password: 
Last login: Sun Jul 25 04:41:40 EET 2021 on pts/2
zibri@zibris:~$
```

Cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

On Unix systems there might be no `lastlog`. Hence I had to combine ideas of @terdon and @Xion345 into one.

On Solaris 8-10 and OpenBSD 4.8 this works good enough:

```
$ last $USER | perl -lane '!/still logged in/ && print "Last login: @F[3..6] from $F[2]" and last'
Last login: Fri Apr 24 08:36 from xxxxxxxxxx.omnit
```

You loose the seconds and the year (because `last` doesn't provide them):

But for HP-UX you need `-R` to get the hostname part:

```
$ last -R $USER | perl -lane '...'
Last login: Fri Apr 24 23:58 from 10.xxx.yyy.82
```

But if you want to get a full hostname + you are on Solaris, you can add `-a` instead. This way the formatting gets a bit of shuffle:

```
$ last -a $USER | perl -lane '!/still logged in/ && print "Last login: @F[2..5] from $F[$#F]" and last'
Last login: Fri Apr 24 08:36 from xxxxxxxxxx.omnitel.lan
```

On OpenBSD you can recover the seconds with `-T`. And the hostname part is a lot wider by default.

But you cannot easily try all the options in a row, because for some systems they might carry opposite meanings.  Eg. Linux:

```
       -R     Suppresses the display of the hostname field.
```

... vs HP-UX:

```
           -R        When used with last and lastb, -R displays the user's
                     host name as it is stored in the files /var/adm/wtmps
                     and /var/adm/btmps, respectively.  The host name is
                     displayed between the tty name and the user's login
                     time.
```

IOW, there is no easy cross-platform way to script this on unices.